# Set level of battery notification in Loki

Tags: release-loki, notifications, battery

By default the notification for low battery is at 10%

[image]

The critically low notification is at about 3% and the imminent shutdown  notification comes immediately after. I find these levels to be too low.

Can they be changed somehow?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/800398/47206):

Low and critical battery percentage is now handled by UPower and not by `gsettings` (more [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/92818/47206)). Instead of using gsettings, you should now edit the file `/etc/UPower/UPower.conf`

Using `gedit` text editor:

```
sudo gedit /etc/UPower/UPower.conf
```

Edit the following lines:

```
UsePercentageForPolicy=true
PercentageLow=15
PercentageCritical=10
PercentageAction=8
```

[image]

And the rest changed accordingly.

Only the setting for the action after critical level (line `CriticalPowerAction=HybridSleep`) [didn't work](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/q/7814/170) until I have created a swap space.