# Battery low and full nothing notification

Tags: release-juno, notifications, battery

How to make notification when battery is low 15%-10% and how to make notification when battery already full in charge?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I have written a custom script that will do as shown below:

[image]

---

**Script:**

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
while true
do
    export DISPLAY=:0.0
    battery_percent=$(acpi -b | grep -P -o '[0-9]+(?=%)')
    if on_ac_power; then
        if [ "$battery_percent" -gt 98 ]; then
            notify-send --app-name=battery "Battery full." "Level: ${battery_percent}% "
        fi
    else
        if [ "$battery_percent" -lt 15 ]; then
            notify-send --app-name=battery "Battery low." "Level: ${battery_percent}% "
        elif [ "$battery_percent" -lt 10 ]; then
            notify-send --app-name=battery "Battery Critical." "Level: ${battery_percent}% "
        fi
    fi
    sleep 300 # (5 minutes)
done
```

---

**Installation:**

Run:

```
sudo apt install acpi
```

Save above script as "*battery_notification.sh*" under "*/usr/local/bin*"

```
sudo chmod +x /usr/local/bin/battery_notification.sh
```

---

**Run Script at start-up:**

Open **System Setting** -> **Applications** -> **Startup**

- Click **Add**
- Enter full path `/usr/local/bin/battery_notification.sh`

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I was searching for the same thing. Here I found a solution to get notifications for low and critically low battery state: [Battery notifications](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/7810/set-level-of-battery-notification-in-loki)

Comment: is there a possibility that we can make a notification for a battery that is full?

Comment: @AhmadShiddiq: Maybe [this](https://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2016/07/ubuntu-battery-monitor-notifications) helps?

Answer (score 0):

For the second part of your question

## ...make notification when battery already full in charge?

You can follow this answer [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/682498/1013655)